# CSV to JSON. Some values are null

Tags: php, json, csv

I build a CSV to JSON PHP File. But it won't work correctly. The value "faktor" is allways null. The value question is sometimes null. I hope you can help me. Thank you!

The PHP File

```
    <?php
$row = 0;
$filename = "launeImTeam.csv";
$questions = array();

if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {   
        $questions[$row] = array(
            "question" => $data[0], 
            "typ" => $data[1],
            "faktor" => $data[2]
        );
        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$final = array("alleFragen"=>$questions);
echo json_encode($final); 

?>
```

Here is the Data of the CSV File. (Its German).

```
Wie sehen Sie Ihren zeitlichen Plan?;fuenf;Qualität;
Ich möchte Kaffee?;fuenf;Qualität;
Sind sie da???;jn;Qualität;
nein?;jn;Qualität;
```

This is the result. :(

```
{
   "alleFragen":[
      {
         "question":"Wie sehen Sie Ihren zeitlichen Plan?",
         "typ":"fuenf",
         "faktor":null
      },
      {
         "question":null,
         "typ":"fuenf",
         "faktor":null
      },
      {
         "question":"Sind sie da???",
         "typ":"jn",
         "faktor":null
      },
      {
         "question":"nein?",
         "typ":"jn",
         "faktor":null
      }
   ]
}
```

Sorry for my English! :)

EDIT: Is it because of the ä ö ü??

Comment: Have you had a look at `$questions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by your values not being encoded as UTF-8. Use iconv() or utf8_encode to convert them from your original encoding (for the CSV file) to UTF-8 before calling `json_encode` on the array. Any value that's not valid UTF-8 will be returned as `null`.

This is noted in [the documentation of json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode).

Answer (score 0):

Default behavior of json_encode is to escape all Unicode characters.

Use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option with json_encode function, if is there any error you will get by `json_last_error()` function.